# Install DataPower certificate in Linux environment?

Tags: ibm-datapower

Need to connect IBM WebSphere and we are asked  to install `datapower` certificate at our end. Can anyone guide me to the installation of certificate at our end (Linux environment?)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Please edit your question to show in which part of linux you want to install the certificate - in the browser? java keystore? or what?

Comment: And also include what type of connection, eg. HTTPS TLS/SSL, client authentication, SSH, SFTP, etc?